# Faucet and wallet deployment on a private PoA set up using puppeth

Tags: etherscan, faucets, poa

I'm trying to setup a private PoA BC using puppeth. While in the background, nodes (sealers and tx submitters) are working fine, I'm facing a problem with deploying a faucet and a wallet using puppeth. Actually these services are marked "service offline", and when I go on their webpages I'm getting "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable". Here's my network stats

[image]

I also have a question about blockchain explorers for private networks, why is puppeth giving the possibility of having a BC explorer only for PoW networks (ethash only, impossible for clique)? Also, is it possible to deploy an etherscan like BC explorer for private networks? I've been using etherparty, but etherscan is definitely better.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For private Ethereum network blockchains, I particularly like (and use) Etherparty.

It is light, very easy to set up and provide just enough information about blocks and transactions.

https://github.com/etherparty/explorer

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://blk.io/ for making a block explorer. It is open source.You can have block explorers for clique also. I have deployed my block explorer for ethereum clique network.